# MySQL MyISAM: Should I disable keys when doing giant deletes?

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have a couple of these MyISAM tables that have billions of rows and 8 pretty complicated indexes.

When I import data, which is once per day, I disable the keys, import from file, then enable the keys. This is reasonably fast.

I just wrote a script to delete certain records, about 1% of them, which will be done once per week. I ran this without disabling the keys as I assumed it needed the indexes to find the records I want to delete.

My issue is that it's stuck `preparing` the first `DELETE` for the last 45 minutes. I don't think it can even delete them within a week! And of course, this needs to be fast as I have to insert more rows each day.

So my question is: will it be more efficient to `ALTER TABLE... DISABLE KEYS` in this case for `DELETE`? It'll take longer to find the records to delete, but it should delete them faster...? (I have no idea.)

I would test it myself, but these tables are not a sandbox where I can test different ideas easily.

Comment: How does your delete query looks like? Is it a delete from where pk = ? or delete from pk in ? or delete from join ?

Comment: One is `delete where pk=`, the other is `delete where pk in (select massive load of rows from other table)`. I'm going to play around with the indexes and have one disabled with another enabled. See if this helps.

Comment: I was having the same kind of issues with big tables and I did use a temp table and put my ids inside the DELETE tablename FROM tablename join temptable on temptable.id = tablename.id and it was like 100 times faster than using pk in (big select)

Comment: So I've figured out that the actual statement inside the `in` (the select from other table) takes a fraction of a second as it is indexed. Then even with no index on the first table it is still `preparing` forever. So I don't think the `in` is the issue.

Comment: OK, I read about the issue. I will try your suggestion. Thanks! http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29423

Comment: if not alreay done so then please consider table partitioning your tables. This would obviously improve speeds.